# Using query in a while loop causing android application to freeze

Tags: query, loop, arcgis-android

I am having some troubles with the while loop + query. What I'm trying to do is track the user location (using onlocationChanged) and keep querying a `FeatureLayer` until the query returns a result and then stop the while loop is using a boolean.
The problem once the "while" loop is launched is that the application freezes, here's my code:

```
boolean noResults=true
while(noResults)

{
    pointGeometry=MyPosition;

//myPosition is changing it's value in "onLocationChanged" using the listener, see code below 

Graphic pointGraphic = new Graphic(pointGeometry, simpleMarker);
SpatialReference spatialRef = MapFragment.mMapView.getSpatialReference();
Unit unit = spatialRef.getUnit();
double adjustedAccuracy = b_dist;
Polygon p = GeometryEngine.buffer(pointGeometry, spatialRef,adjustedAccuracy, unit);
Query q = new Query();
q.setGeometry(p);
q.setSpatialRelationship(SpatialRelationship.INTERSECTS);
fLayer.selectFeatures(q, SELECTION_METHOD.NEW, callback4);
}


public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

                double locy = loc.getLatitude();
            double locx = loc.getLongitude();
            Point wgspoint = new Point(locx, locy);
            mLocation = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(wgspoint,
                    SpatialReference.create(4326),
                    mMapView.getSpatialReference());

//Here's where myPosition changes its value.

            myPosition = mLocation;  
}



CallbackListener<FeatureSet> callback4 = new CallbackListener<FeatureSet>() {

        public void onCallback(FeatureSet fSet) {   
            Graphic[] grh=fSet.getGraphics();

            if(grh.length>0){  
                        noResults=false;
                        showTaost("there's a result");
                    } 
});
```

Is there an alternative to the while loop to fix this? If not, how can I use something like a delay (query the Feature Layer every 5 secondes or something like that)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem using a "Handler" that query the Feature Layer every 5 seconds, this stops the main thread from generating application not responding error:

```
   Handler m_handler=new Handler();
    Runnable m_runnable;
    m_runnable = new Runnable(){
   public void run() {

  //query code here
m_handler.postDelayed(m_runnable, 5000);

    }
   };
  m_handler.postDelayed(m_runnable, 0);
```